# String converter program not working

Tags: python

I am trying to make a basic program which translates a string ATGTACATGGGCATAGCCATATA to its RNA sequence, which is UACAUGUACCCGUAUCGGUAUAU.

But instead the output is: CCCCCUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU

But it's not quite working. I think the problem is it goes through the entire string with each letter individually.

I am very new to bioinformatics programming so any suggestions would be welcomed.

```
DNA = "ATGTACATGGGCATAGCCATATA"
dna_length = len(DNA)

print("DNA: " + DNA)
print()
print("Length of DNA in base pairs: "+ str(dna_length))

RNA = []
for char in DNA:
    if char == "G":
        RNA.append("C")
for line in DNA:
    if char == "C":
        RNA.append("G")
for line in DNA:
    if char == "A":
        RNA.append("U")
for line in DNA:
    if char == "T":
        RNA.append("A")

print("".join(RNA))
```

Comment: I think its cuz you have.... `for line in DNA: if char == "C":` shouldn't it be `for char in DNA: if char =="C":`

Comment: Oops sorry I know it should be char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `dict` to perform your substitutions, then use a generator expression within `join` to perform your translation.

```
>>> RNA = {'G':'C', 'C':'G', 'A':'U', 'T':'A'}
>>> DNA = 'ATGTACATGGGCATAGCCATATA'
>>> translated = ''.join(RNA[i] for i in DNA)
>>> translated
'UACAUGUACCCGUAUCGGUAUAU'
```

Comment: Thank you. Lots of great answers and solutions in this question, much appreciated

Comment: Note that there's no real advantage of genexp here except readability.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're looping over the same list four times and also modifying the changes that were made in the previous loops. So, use a single loop with multiple if-else conditions:

```
RNA = []
for char in DNA:
    if char == "G":
        RNA.append("C")
    elif char == "C":
        RNA.append("G")
    elif char == "A":
        RNA.append("U")
    elif char == "T":
        RNA.append("A")

print("".join(RNA))
```

Best solution will be to use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> s = "ATGTACATGGGCATAGCCATATA"
>>> tab = maketrans('GCAT', 'CGUA')
>>> s.translate(tab)
'UACAUGUACCCGUAUCGGUAUAU'
```

In Python 3 we can do it without any imports:

```
>>> s = "ATGTACATGGGCATAGCCATATA"
>>> s.translate({ord(k): v for k, v in zip('GCAT', 'CGUA')})
'UACAUGUACCCGUAUCGGUAUAU'
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `str.maketrans` which makes a translation table from 1 set of characters to another, and `str.translate` which applies such mapping to a string; this should be the fastest way to do this, thus

```
>>> DNA_2_RNA = str.maketrans('CGAT', 'GCUA')
>>> DNA = 'ATGTACATGGGCATAGCCATATA'
>>> RNA = DNA.translate(DNA_2_RNA)
>>> RNA
'UACAUGUACCCGUAUCGGUAUAU'
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary though if this is python 3, yours does not work as `string` does not have `maketrans` ;)

Comment: I think that string.maketrans (this answer) will be faster because it uses a simple lookup table, as opposed to the other solution which uses a dict.

Comment: The imports are not for the Python 3 solution.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Code:

```
DNA = "ATGTACATGGGCATAGCCATATA"
dna_length = len(DNA)

print("DNA: " + DNA)
print()
print("Length of DNA in base pairs: "+ str(dna_length))

RNA = []
for char in DNA:
    if char == "G":
        RNA.append("C")
    elif char == "C":
        RNA.append("G")
    elif char == "A":
        RNA.append("U")
    elif char == "T":
        RNA.append("A")

print("".join(RNA))
```

Result:

```
DNA: ATGTACATGGGCATAGCCATATA
()
Length of DNA in base pairs: 23
UACAUGUACCCGUAUCGGUAUAU
```